# out of memory errors in Users Import through feed in grails

Tags: grails, out-of-memory

We have a grails application and we are importing users through CSV feed. User Domain object has huge list of fields (85 total). And we are writing the Import functionality using Hibernate api ... to insert into User table. 
Right now we are getting out of memory errors if we load like 2000 users since User domain object in memory.

Is there any way to optimize the design to remove the out of memory errors. like not loading all columns of User domain on load each column when required. how to reduce the memory consumption?

Comment: I would recommend NOT doing this in a web application. Upload the file and then have a job import it.  Would this work?

Comment: we are going to run this service in a quartz scheduler not through ui

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Ted Naleid's great article on batch processing:

http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/

The last part of the article (Grails Performance Tweaks) REALLY helped me solve a similar problem.  Adding the "cleanUpGorm" function and running it every 100 records has let us process tens of thousands of records with no memory problems.